# Web service that publishes text documents to the cloud so they can be dynamically retrieved via API call and rendered on client side?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, persistence, client-side

I have been building out a website in angular with the aim of running no web server on the backend and using web services to retrieve whatever dynamic content can be retrieved.

I built a blogger widget yesterday that dynamically retrieves most recent blog-posts from a range of configurable blogs and renders them on the webpage. I would ideally like to do something similar with Google Drive and render the content of public documents by calling an API.

Two questions:

1. Should I be dynamically retrieving and rendering this contents in the first place, or should I simply create static HTML files? Maybe my desire to separate logic from data is  just over-complicating things.
2. If I am not over-complicating matters, where should I persist these files? I could potentially post them as blog entries and retrieve them as I did for my blogger widget. I do feel like since they are not blogs, they should not be treated as such. Is there an API call for Google Drive that would enable me to get the contents of a Google Doc (which is accessible either publicly or by anyone with the link) as HTML and return them in a JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know the reason you need to access Google drive? I'm assuming from your suggestion, of creating static HTML pages, google drive would be used merely as a content management system (CMS) and is not a pre-existing requirement.

If this is the case then you have a more fundamental question to answer.

Will you need to update the content retrieved from the content management system more than once?

If the answer is no then, KISS (Keep it simple stupid). Go with static files, served from the same place you're serving the angular app from.

If the answer is yes, you do need a CMS, then I would go with one which has build in REST support. I would recommend [HIPPO](http://www.onehippo.com/en/why-hippo-cms) which you could host on a free Amazon web services server running tomcat.

At the end of the day, the less moving parts, the less things that can fail. For performance and your own sanity I would push static content. A useful resource to make the publishing and maintaining static content a lot easier is [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

Comment: I suppose I think Drive would be a great way to be able to update the contents of webpages without needing to push additional commits... I was hoping to avoid my own backend, but HIPPO looks awesome. I just have to decide whether its worth going with my own backend...

Comment: Agreed, and if you find/develop a REST interface for Drive let me know :) If you have somewhere to store your app at the moment, it sounds like the most straightforward solution for you would be to use something like Jekyll, or raw HTML if you like typing, and go with the static content solution.